# LINQ to filter included entity

Tags: c#, linq

I have this **LINQ**

```
var userGroups = this.ObjectContext.UserGroups.Include("Users");
```

The problem is that I have to filter "**Users**" if it is active by field **IsActive**.

So, I need to filter by filed of the including table "**Users**" where is **IsActive**.

How I can do it with LINQ?

Thank you!

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__
P.S.**

I try to do the following but I am not sure...

```
 var userGroups = this.ObjectContext.UserGroups;

 foreach (var userGroup in userGroups )
 {
     var ussers = this.ObjectContext.Users.Where(f => f.UserGroupID == item.ID && f.IsActive == true).ToList<User>();

     userGroup.Users = users;
 }
```

Comment: Clarify. Are you looking for userGroups that have active users? Or are you looking for the user groups based on a particular user? Or are you looking for the active users in all the user groups?

Comment: I need to get all userGroups with all associated Users but Users should be filtered by field IsActive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this linq-to-entities? Then it is not possible to do any kind of filtering to the included entities that are eager loaded. Ladislav Mrnka wrote about it in his latest [blog post](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/04/eager-loading-improvements-needed-in-ef/).

It is of course possible to use linq-to-objects to handle the entities once loaded into memory, but if you only want a fraction of the available entities that would be inefficient.

A linq-to-objects solution:

```
var userGroups = this.ObjectContext.UserGroups.Include("Users")
.Select(ug => new UserGroup {
Name = ug.Name,
// Copy all fields
Users = ug.Users.Where(u => u.Active)
});
```

Comment: So I have to play with FOREACH somehow... Right?

Answer (score 1):

Could you reverse the statement to be

```
var userGroups = this.ObjectContext.Users.Include("UserGroups").Where(f=>f.IsActive == true);
```

And then use a GroupBy on the UserGroups field?

Comment: No... In this case I get the Users as the top level entities. I don't need it. It should be UserGroups.